# How can I loop through a specific part of a YAML file with Liquid?

Tags: html, loops, yaml, jekyll, liquid

I want to create a list from the `# Tasks` segment of this YAML file. The loop I have is creating `li` elements, but they're empty. What am I missing?

**YAML**

```
# Domain title
title: Hello world

# Task list
taskList: 
  - task: Task 1
    subtaskList:
      - subtask: Subtask 1
        tagList:
          - tag: case5
          - tag: case2
        badges:
          - tag: intIntCon
          - tag: query
  - task: Task 2
    subtaskList:
      - subtask: Subtask 1
        tagList:
          - tag: case5
          - tag: case2
        badges:
          - tag: intIntCon
          - tag: query
```

**Liquid**

```
{% for data in site.data.sourcing[taskList] %}
    <li class="task-card">
        {{data.task}}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the loop to: `{% for taskData in site.data.sourcing.taskList %}`